# How to load another html file using JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a website, and I'm trying to figure out how to load a page.

For example:

You click on the navigator "Home" then a the bottom of the screen It loads a page witch text saying for example "Hello Word!".

Does anybody know what to do? I'm pretty sure It involves JavaScript.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_links_-_lets_build_a_web#What_are_links.3F

Comment: Not very helpful of my understanding, sorry.

Comment: Are you talking about single page applications? You always stay on the same page, but the content is reloaded.

Comment: Just like how this website works - habbosecrets.com. When you click "News" It loads text's and images.

Comment: I actually think this is a useful question + answer - so many answers on a similar topic jump straight in with a framework

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To dynamically load content, you could make an AJAX call using `XMLHttpRequest()`.

In this example a url is passed to the `loadPage()` function, in which the loaded content is returned.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadPage(href)
            {
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("GET", href, false);
                xmlhttp.send();
                return xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div onClick="document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML = 
                      loadPage('hello-world.html');">Home</div>

        <div id="bottom"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

When the div element containing text of "Home" is clicked, it sets the html of div element with id of "bottom" to content found in the "hello-world.html" document at the same relative location.

**hello-world.html**

```
<p>hello, world</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, but a question in mind. What about more then 1 pages. What would happen?

Comment: Multiple documents may be loaded, replacing or appending content by repeatedly calling this implementation.

Comment: @JasonSturges Why does it work though? I mean xmlhttp is async so when you return `xmlhttp.responseText` it should be empty because it should have run before the file has been downloaded, at least most of the times. But it does work why

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Above demonstrates a synchronous request.

Comment: nvm i just rerealized that last parameter which is `false` defines whether request is going to be async or not. :D

Comment: Syntax: `open(method,url,async)`

Comment: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/habla/rx3h8kp7/. I had to load jsfiddle into the div rather than a hello.html due to cross site security restrictions, but it demonstrates the principle.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what you are looking for is a single page application.

There are plenty of technologies implementing it, but not that easy.

Here is a tutorial I followed for doing it : http://andru.co/building-a-simple-single-page-application-using-angularjs

If you want to go further with SPAs, you will certainly need angular templates.

Answer (score -1):

It's not necessary to use Ajax calls to load html. Use them when need the server to process data successfully before loading the page, if processing was successful.

If you don't have this concern, and you just want to load the html without data processing, a simple **anchor tag** will suffice:

```
 <a href="path/to/hello.html">click</a>
```