# Load html content in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

**What I'm trying to do :**

I'm working on an Angular SPA, and I'd like to load some html content in a `scope` in order to display it.

**What I did :**

According to SO questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535055/load-html-file-contents-to-div-without-the-use-of-iframes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930361/how-to-load-another-html-file-using-js)), I create a function which loads the targeted file and I load its content in my `scope` (code is from Jason Sturges suggestion) :

```
 function loadPage(href) {

      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("GET", href, false);
      xmlhttp.send();
      return xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
```

Used with : `$scope.pageContent = loadPage("html_file.html")`

**Problem :**

At that time, the html content is loaded. The problem is that, instead of being interpreted by Chrome, it appears as 'plain text' (I guess it's the right term for that), like this :

```
 <div><h4>...</h4></div>
```

What should I do ?

Comment: you should assgin it to a scope varialbe in a ajax callback.

Comment: Is there a special reason you're not using [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)?

Comment: No, I had just no idea on how to do that, so I get some ideas from SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your angularJs version, it can change, but based on angular 1.3, you should use the [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive with the [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service :

In template :

```
<div ng-bind-html="securedHtml"></div>
```

In controller :

```
$scope.securedHtml= $sce.trustAsHtml(yourRawHtmlFromServer);
```

And like the other answer said, use the internal [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service (or [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource)) to make your ajax calls.